# QString to std::string to const char* conversion does not work in assignment

Tags: c++, qstring

This code:

```
std::string a("TEST1");
const char* a_c = a.c_str();
QString b("TEST2");
const char* b_c = b.toStdString().c_str();

std::string s1 = std::string("A: ") + a.c_str();
std::string s2 = std::string("A: ") + a_c;
std::string s3 = std::string("B: ") + b.toStdString().c_str();
std::string s4 = std::string("B: ") + b_c;

std::cout << s1 << std::endl;
std::cout << s2 << std::endl;
std::cout << s3 << std::endl;
std::cout << s4 << std::endl;
```

prints:

```
A: TEST1
A: TEST1
B: TEST2
B: B:
```

I don't know what's happened on the last `cout`. (Obviously I can print directly the `std::string`, but this piece of code is an example on a bigger project where I need the C-style string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During writing the question I found the trivial bug: after this line

```
const char* b_c = b.toStdString().c_str();
```

the `std::string` returned by `b.toStdString()` no longer exists, so the destructor was called and the `b_c` pointer is no more valid. Instead, the

```
std::string("B: ") + b.toStdString().c_str();
```

copy into the new string the value of the concatenation, so the invalidation of `b.toStdString()` is no more a problem.

Obviously `a_c` is not a problem because `a` is never destroyed.